# To be or not to be in the Dark Brotherhood and a Guild Master

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

First of all I'm trying to avoid repeating this question:
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40039/what-should-i-consider-when-deciding-to-join-or-destroy-the-dark-brotherhood

I was reading http://elderscrolls.wikia.com and I have a few doubts about the history line. I read that you can kill Astrid, but then you can join the Dark Brotherhood anyway, if you do not choose to start another history. Is that correct?

My idea is to try to complete this questline but then kill 'em all.
So I think I'll kill Astrid first.

My questions are:

1. If I kill Astrid can I really join the dark brotherhood and then
   once I've completed that questline destroy 'em all?
2. If not, is there a way to do that?
3. If I only choose to destroy them, can I get the Shadowmere? How?
4. Is there a consequence for being a member of the dark brotherhood with any NPC?
5. In relation to these, I'm married with Mjoll the Lioness. If I
   become a Guild Master will I have problems?

I'd be grateful for any comments or answers. 
Thanks and kind regards.

Please before you downvote this question, comment or edit why you think this question should be changed.

Comment: I joined the DB, you get some good gear. I feel you _gain_ more by joining than destroying. As like all the other guilds. (plus, correct me if i'm wrong, there isn't a maximum amount of guilds join (except for the obvious where you cant be a vamp if you're a werewolf.))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only choose one of two things:

1. Kill Astrid and destroy the Brotherhood (and not obtain shadowmere)
2. Join the Brotherhood

Also, there are barely any consequences. No one will really have anything but maybe different speech options for intimidate.

Of course there always are console commands to fix your needs if you feel like cheating.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you kill Atrid you just get her armor and the Blade of Woe, which you'll get anyway.
2. No way to do those quests unless it glitches or you have a mod on the PC version.
3. No Shadowmere for you if you kill her.
4. Not really, but if you pickpocket someone, they notice and you escape they will possibly send someone after you. They will be Dark Brotherhood if you're not part of it, otherwise they'll be mercenaries.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Dragonborn DLC and join the Brotherhood, you may randomly encounter a group of 3 Morag Tong assassins on Solstheim looking for you(can happen multiple times) after completing a certain quest on Solstheim.

I have never married Mjoll, but I have had her as a follower even after I was named Guild Master. I don't think she has any way of finding out, unless you have her follow you into the Guild headquarters and chat up some of the others like Delvin or Vex. Even then, she may be oblivious(the AI interactions in the game can be pretty decent at times, but they aren't THAT great).